# sort 2-d array using stl sort()

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I have a 2-d array, containing only 0 or 1.
I want to sort it in descend order on rows (no change on each column) using STL sort algorithm. but I don't know how to pass the parameter and how to write the compare function in sort(first, last, comp);
like:

```
0 1 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
```

would be sorted like this:

```
1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
0 1 1 1
```

my data structure is like this:

```
int **table = 0;
table = new int *[row];
for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
table[i] = new int[column];
```

I can only write the sort function like this:

```
sort(a[0], a[0]+row, compare_function);

bool compare_function(int a[], int b[])
{
    int i =0;
    while(a[i]==0 ||a[i]==1)
    {
        if(a[i]>b[i])
            return true;
        else
            i++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Can some one help me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this not ALWAYS true? 
`[i]==0 ||a[i]==1`
(aside from when you read outside the defined area of your array, in which case the content is completely undefined - there could be a gazzilion zeros in a row before you get to a place in memory that causes your program to crash!)

Comment: `0 1 1 1` to `1 1 0 1` ?? that's not sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to sort looks wrong to me (though you never said what `a` is).  It should be `sort(table, table+row, compare_function)`

But I'd do it a bit differently anyway (`std::lexicographical_compare` comes from `<algorithm>`):

```
struct compare_rows {
  const int cols;
  compare_rows(int cols_) : cols(cols_) {}
  bool operator()(const int a[], const int b[]) const {
    // a b reversed to give descending sort
    return lexicographical_compare(b, b+cols, a, a+cols);
    }
  };
```

And use it like:

```
sort(table, table+row, compare_rows(column))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your compare function to:

```
bool comp(const int a[], const int b[]){
  int sum1 = std::accumulate(a, a + column, 0);
  int sum2 = std::accumulate(b, b + column, 0);
  return sum1 < sum2;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't give descending order, nor does it sort lexicographically (based on his example it's what he wants)

Comment: You're right. Although I can invert the comparison to give descending order, it does not necessarily sort lexicographically