# How to sort 2D array using built in sort function

Tags: c++

I want to compare a 2D array with my custom compare function. I also reference some similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997083/sort-2-d-array-using-stl-sort), but it doesn't work.

Following is what I did (compare 2D array with row and I need to use array instead of `vector`):

```cpp
int n, dim;
int box[33][33];
bool cmp(const int a[], const int b[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        if(a[i] != b[i])
            return a[i] < b[i];
    }
    return a[dim] < b[dim];
}
int main()
{


    while(cin>>n>>dim){
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++){
                cin>>box[i][j];
            }
            box[i][dim] = i+1; // store index of box
            sort(box[i], box[i]+dim);
        }

        sort(box, box + n, cmp); // This line is where I want to modify

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++){
                cout<<box[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's `box`? Show a [mcve]

Comment: What's `dim`?...

Comment: edit. `dim` is column. `n` is row. `box` is 2 D array.

Comment: @Armin ,  I assume no over bound problem in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a 2D array in C++ using built in functions(or any other method)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931669/sort-a-2d-array-in-c-using-built-in-functionsor-any-other-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `std::qsort` in this case, by providing the appropriate comparator:

```
int cmp(const void *l, const void *r)
{
    const int *a = (const int*)l;
    const int *b = (const int*)r;

    for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] != b[i])
            return (a[i] > b[i]) - (a[i] < b[i]);
    }
    return (a[dim] > b[dim]) - (a[dim] < b[dim]);
}
```

and then calling it like this:

```
std::qsort(box, n, sizeof(int) * (dim + 1), cmp);
```

You could also simplify the comparator like this:

```
int comp(const void *l, const void *r)
{
    const int *a = (const int*)l;
    const int *b = (const int*)r;

    return std::lexicographical_compare(b, b + dim + 1, a, a + dim +1);
}
```

Note that the arguments are in opposite order to get ascending order.

Comment: Yes, I knew `qsort` can do. I'm wondering `sort` can't do this anyway?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `std::sort` *cannot* sort like this.